# Compare Tables In SQL server from android studio

Tags: java, android, sql

I am developing an app in which the user first login,and if he doesn't have an account he will register after finishing that step he will be directed to a page,there he will add users to his profile like.. his own family members anything like that and when they add a user its going to be saved in a table on an external server(SQL) and then get that in the user list view but how can the user only see his own users and nobody else can see his users except him and so for all other users,like their own data?!

i didn't figure out how to do this yet,any one help me with this task?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is quite open ended.  How are you connecting to the server? A REST Api? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like your question is about how to design your database rather than the technical details of how to call the database from you code and display results on your pages?

You need to split your data up into multiple tables. Each table should have a unique id (the id for each row should be different). Then you link rows in tables together by referencing the ids.

One way to achieve what you want would be like this.

A user table:

```
User
----
Id
Username
Password (hashed)
```

A family members  table:

```
Family_Members
--------------
User
Member
```

You put pairs of relationships in the `family_members` table. So you would put the id of one user in the first column `user` and the id of one of their family members in the second column `member`. Then you have a row for every relationship. When you load the table, you find all the rows where `user` is equal to the user id you are loading.

For example:

```
User
+--+--------+--------+
|Id|Username|Password|
| 1|Bob     |abc     |
| 2|Dad     |def     |
| 3|Mum     |ghi     |
+--+--------+--------+
```

And..

```
Family_members
+----+------+
|User|Member|
| 1  |  2   |
| 1  |  3   |
| 2  |  1   |
| 2  |  3   |
| 3  |  1   |
| 3  |  2   |
+----+------+
```

Then when you load family members for `Bob`, who's id is `1`, you load all the rows from the `family_members` table that have `User==1`. Then you go back to the `User` table and load the details you want for each family member, and get an object like:

```
User:
 - username: Bob
 - password: abc
 - family:
    - User:
       - username: Dad
    - User:
       - username: Mum
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: but just one more question,after i finish creating the database and the table how can i connect the app with the table i mean how can i say in the app that if the id of the user is equal one search for the member that has the id of one?

Comment: Exactly how you would do it depends on what technology you are using between the Java application and the database. If you are not using an orm like hibernate you would do it via a sql query, for example ```select * from user u inner join family_members fm on u.id = fm.member where fm.user = ?```. For more detail, it might be good to ask another question.

Comment: Thanks so much i definitely would ask another question anyways thanks for the help